# Trouble with MIN clause

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I am having trouble displaying the youngest employee per department.

There is another table named `department`, which simply says the department number and department name. I have also tried a WHERE EXISTS clause, and no luck.

```
   SELECT emp_department_number, 
          emp_name, 
          MIN(TRUNC(((current_date - emp_dateofbirth)/(365.25)))) "age" 
     FROM employee
 GROUP BY emp_department_number, emp_name
 ORDER BY emp_department_number;
```

I also have this, but it generates the same results..

```
 SELECT emp_department_number, emp_name, min(TRUNC(((current_date -      emp_dateofbirth)/(365.25)))) "age" from employee
 JOIN department
 ON dpt_num=emp_department_number
 WHERE EXISTS (select min(emp_dateofbirth) from employee)
 GROUP BY emp_department_number, emp_name
 order by emp_department_number;



 EMP_DEPARTMENT_NUMBER EMP_NAME                        age
 -------------- ------------------------------ ----------
 1              Ramon, Emma                           25
 1              Tin, Rina                             69
 3              Mason, John                           68
 3              Roberson, Wayne                       50
 3              Zan, Shelis                           51
 7              Hockman, Ronnie                       62
 7              Lam, Annie                            37
 7              Smith, Ramon                          60
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using Oracle, you can use `MONTHS_BETWEEN` to calculate the exact age.
And to find the youngest, you can skip the age calculation and use `emp_dateofbirth` directly.

```
 SELECT emp_department_number, emp_name
      , trunc(MONTHS_BETWEEN(emp_dateofbirth, current_date)/12) as age
   from employee e
  WHERE e.emp_dateofbirth = (
        SELECT MAX(emp_dateofbirth) 
          FROM employee x
         WHERE x.emp_department_number = e.emp_department_number )
```

You can read as "for each employee, return it if his birth date is equal to the max birth date of his department".

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the `ROW_NUMBER()` analytic function (I added in a potential join to the department table to get the name):

```
SELECT dept_name, empl, age
FROM (
  SELECT EMP_DEPARTMENT_NUMBER AS dept,
       EMP_NAME AS empl,
       TRUNC((CURRENT_DATE - emp_dateofbirth) / 365.25) AS age,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EMP_DEPARTMENT_NUMBER ORDER BY emp_dateofbirth ASC) AS rn
  FROM employee
) E
JOIN department d
  ON e.dept = d.dept_id
WHERE rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, what you need is [the `FIRST_VALUE` analytic function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions057.htm):

```
SELECT emp_department_number,
       emp_name,
       TRUNC((CURRENT_DATE - emp_dateofbirth) / 365.25) age
  FROM employee
 WHERE emp_num IN
        ( SELECT FIRST_VALUE(emp_num) OVER
                    ( PARTITION BY emp_department_number
                          ORDER BY emp_dateofbirth DESC
                    )
            FROM employee
           GROUP
              BY emp_department_number
        )
;
```